# How can I configure a TransportSecurityBindingElement for a CustomBinding within a web.config?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have the following (reduced) code that I'd like to configure through a web.config

```
var security = new TransportSecurityBindingElement();
security.EndpointSupportingTokenParameters.SignedEncrypted.Add(new UserNameSecurityTokenParameters());

var binding = new CustomBinding(security);
```

Is it possible to configure this custom binding using the web config? If it is possible how could I configure the endpoint supporting token parameters? I've tried The following config, however it does not validate against DotNetConfig.xsd:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <customBinding>
      <binding name="SomeBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00">
        <transportSecurity> <!-- Fails validation -->
            <!-- How do I configure the EndpointSupportingTokenParameters -->             
        </transportSecurity>
      </binding>
    </customBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
    ...
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just use `customBinding/security`, perhaps with an `authenticationMode` of `UserNameOverTransport`:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding>
          <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Failing that, you could try adding the token manually to [`issuedTokenParameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa734714.aspx):

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding>
          <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport">
              <issuedTokenParameters tokenType="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2006/05/identitymodel/tokens/UserName" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

(tokenType stolen from `UserNameSecurityTokenParameters`)

To be honest, it's probably so much hassle that it's easier to just do it in code. If you need to to be different per environment, define the factory in the config and use DI to use it to create the binding.